# django-admin --version error

Tags: django, python-2.7

I was working on a Django project and I ran to the error below please help.

I tried to check my django version with the " django-admin --version " command and i ran into this error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named south
```

Answer (score 0):

You have include `south` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings, but it is not installed.

From the traceback, it looks as if you are using Django 1.7 or later, so South is no longer required. You should remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.